# Loading another model from an SDF ros2 humble

Tags: gazebo, ros2, sdf

I'm trying to include another sdf with , I can load it properly with an absolute path to the file but I want to make it a relative path. Structure is as follows:

- package

  - src
  - models
  - worlds

    - model_1.sdf
    - model_2.sdf

For example I want to load model 2 inside of model 1.
I can only find examples which are outdated, if anybody can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Using ROS2 humble with gazebo fortress

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote: "I'm trying to include another sdf with ," so... with what?

Answer (score 0):

as I am not able to comment, I am writing my suggestion in answer section.

I am assuming that you want to add the same model in the sdf. You can include the models using the merge tag in sdf. Just for an example:

```
<!-- <include>
  <uri>
    https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Coke Can
  </uri>
</include>

<include>
  <merge>true</merge>
  <name>my_can</name>
  <uri>
    https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Coke Can
  </uri>
  <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0 </pose>
</include> -->
```

You can refer the sdformat documentation and different tags information here:
http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=model

Answer (score 0):

To include models in the SDF file, you need to write the `models` directory path to the environment variable `IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`, which would allow it to be visible.
After which, you can reference models in your SDF with the following syntax:

```
<include>
   <uri>model://aws_robomaker_warehouse_RoofB_01</uri>
</include>
```

**Note**: Your models have to be well-defined with a config file.
For reference example you can check out [this](https://github.com/blackcoffeerobotics/bcr_bot) repository. It includes models defined in the repository in its world SDF.

Answer (score 0):

you can [post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104695/spawning-an-sdf-model-in-ros-humble.) refer to this Post, if u need any help, let me know. I was able to do it.

Steps to Follow:

1.Create a Models Folder in your Directory(package file) and store the sdf file there. I have created a single Folder named Box inside the Models File

- Models

  - Box

    - model.config
    - model.sdf
    - meshes(folder)

      - mesh1.dae
      - mesh2.stl
      - mesh3.stl

below is the info inside present in the all the files.

a. Model.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <model>
    <name>Box</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <sdf version='1.6'>model.sdf</sdf>
 <author>
<name>name</name>
<email>name@email.address</email>
</author>
<description>This is a box</description>
```

b. model.sdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
<model name="Box">
<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
<static>true</static>
<link name="link">
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://box/meshes/mesh1.dae</uri>
        <scale>0.25 0.25 0.25</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://box/meshes/mesh1.dae</uri>
        <scale>0.25 0.25 0.25</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>
```

c. How to use the Launch File in python

```
spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros',
                    executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    name="spawn_sdf_entity",
                    arguments=[ '-entity','Box','-file', LaunchConfiguration('sdf_model'),
                                '-x','1.0',
                                '-y','1.0',
                                '-z', '0.0',
                                '-R','0.0',
                                '-P','0.0',
                                '-Y','0.0'
                                ], output='screen')


return LaunchDescription([
    sdf_model,
    spawn_entity,
])
```

I hope this will be useful for everyone!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/19382)

Comment: I will add it below as an Answer