# Spawning an Sdf Model in ROS humble

Tags: ros-humble, sdformat, sdf, spawn-model

I have created an Object using Blender and was able to add the Add to the Path File in Ros Humble Gazebo it worked, how to open the same SDF file using Python Launch file.

Comment: Please do not put the answer inside your question. It's OK to answer your own question if you find a good solution.

Comment: but why not? I think i found a Solution, so i thought i will share it for others. But i will change it now

Comment: You want to use the answer section because when you use the search box at the top of this page, the search results will tell you how many answers a particular question has. If it's zero, people probably do not click on it.

Comment: ok, understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Steps to Follow:

1.Create a Models Folder in your Directory(package file) and store the sdf file there. I have created a single Folder named Box inside the Models File

- Models

  - Box

    - model.config
    - model.sdf
    - meshes(folder)

      - mesh1.dae
      - mesh2.stl
      - mesh3.stl

a. Model.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <model>
    <name>Box</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <sdf version='1.6'>model.sdf</sdf>
 <author>
<name>name</name>
<email>name@email.address</email>
</author>
<description>This is a box</description>
```

b. model.sdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
<model name="Box">
<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
<static>true</static>
<link name="link">
  <collision name="collision">
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://box/meshes/mesh1.dae</uri>
        <scale>0.25 0.25 0.25</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://box/meshes/mesh1.dae</uri>
        <scale>0.25 0.25 0.25</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>
```

c. How to use the Launch File in python

```
spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros',
                    executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    name="spawn_sdf_entity",
                    arguments=[ '-entity','Box','-file', LaunchConfiguration('sdf_model'),
                                '-x','1.0',
                                '-y','1.0',
                                '-z', '0.0',
                                '-R','0.0',
                                '-P','0.0',
                                '-Y','0.0'
                                ], output='screen')


return LaunchDescription([
    sdf_model,
    spawn_entity,
])
```

I hope this will be useful for everyone!!

SYSTEM:

ROS2 Humble
Linux ubuntu 22